# jQuery multi form submit individually

Tags: jquery, forms

I have two forms on page

```
    <div class="list">
    <div class="item"><a href="javascript: void(0);" class="okrug">Area 1</a>
    <div class="okrug_box">
    <form method="post" class="okrug_form">

        <div class="success" style="display: none;">New item is added.</div>

        <div class="label">Opština</div>

        <div class="field"><input type="text" id="opstina" name="opstina" /></div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <input type="hidden" name="oid" id="oid" value="2" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit">

        <p><a href="javascript: void(0);" id="close">Close</a></p>

    </form>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="list">
    <div class="item"><a href="javascript: void(0);" class="okrug">Area 2</a>
    <div class="okrug_box">

    <form method="post" class="okrug_form">

        <div class="success" style="display: none;">New item is added.</div>

        <div class="label">Opština</div>
        <div class="field"><input type="text" id="opstina" name="opstina" /></div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <input type="hidden" name="oid" id="oid" value="1" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit">


        <p><a href="javascript: void(0);" id="close">Close</a></p>

    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I need to submit them individually with same jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.okrug').click(function() {

    if($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('div.okrug_box').slideUp('normal');
    } else {
        $('div.okrug_box').slideUp('normal');    
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    }
});

$('a#close').click(function(){
    $('div.okrug_box').slideUp('normal');
})


//HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD
$("div.okrug_box").hide();

$(".okrug_form").submit(function() {  
// we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below  
var opstina = $('#opstina').attr('value');
var oid = $('#oid').attr('value');
var part = $('#part').attr('value');
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "okrug.php",  
        data: "part="+ part +"&oid="+ oid +"&opstina="+ opstina,  
        success: function(){  
            $('div.success').fadeIn();
            setTimeout("$('div.success').fadeOut();", 6000);
        }  
    });  
return false;  
});  
});
```

How can I do this? Here is a preview http://jsfiddle.net/WvQXQ/

Comment: Submitting a form in the regular sense will cause a new page to load based on the result of the form submission. So doing it twice won't be a good idea. Can you not simulate the form submissions with two ajax `POST`s? How do you want the page to look after the submissions?

Comment: he is using return false a the end of the submit handler, therefore it won't go to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(".okrug_form .submit").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // submit all forms with a class of okrug_form
  $(".okrug_form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the form's onSubmit attribute and passing the form element into the function so that you can directly access the values. I have a modified version of your code up here: http://jsfiddle.net/8dZ8m/1/ (first time using jsfiddle, so hopefully I did it right).

**Notable differences:**

- onSubmit was added to both forms (If the function is only tied to the submit button the user may accidentally bypass the js handler by hitting enter. Using onSubmit takes care of this)
- Values are retrieved off of the submitted form via .elements[field_name].value

Using duplicate CSS ids is invalid, so if you are going to continue using those they should be changed to be unique.

I was not able to find the 'part' form element, so my code generates an error on submit. The field needs to be added, or that line needs to be removed.

Hope that helps!